# Defining custom unmarshalling for non-built in types

Tags: json, go

Most of us know that a JSON object can be unmarshaled with JSON tags:

```
var jsonData = `{"name": "Brown Bear"}`

type Elephant struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
}
```

This is because `string` is a built in types. But what if `Name` were not a built in type, and we wanted to use this type across different structs?

```
var jsonData = `{"name": "Brown Bear"}`

type Elephant struct {
    Name Name   `json:"name"`  // Unmarshalling fails here
}

type Feline struct {
    Name Name   `json:"name"`  // Unmarshalling fails here
}

type Bear struct {
    Name Name   `json:"name"`  // Unmarshalling fails here
}

type Name struct {
    CommonName     string
    ScientificName string  // This field should intentionally be blank
}
```

Is there a way we can define the `Name` type so that the `json` unmarshaller knows how to unmarshal it?

PS: The solution I want to avoid is creating `UnmarshalJSON` methods for `Elephant`, `Feline`, and `Bear` above. It would be better to create a method just for the `Name` type.

Comment: Why would unmarshalling fail as written?

Comment: Because you're trying to assign a `string` to a struct called `Name`.

Comment: You haven't shown the JSON, so there's no way to answer this question with certainty, but if the JSON structure matches the Go object structure, it works just fine: https://play.golang.org/p/WVLAc0hUqh

Comment: If you *do* need custom unmarshalling, there's no reason you would add it to each type that uses `Name`. Just add an `UnmarshalJSON` to `Name` itself.

Comment: I see your confusion. I'll edit the question so it's more clear.

Comment: Just create the custom `UnmarshalJSON` or `UnmarshalText` on `Name`.

Comment: @hlin117 nothing stops you from doing what you wish for in your last sentence of the question.

Comment: @mkopriva Ultimately you don't want to define an `UnmarshalJSON` function for all of those types, it's not a scalable solution. It's more scalable to define it on the `Name` type.

Comment: @adrian It looks like defining `UnmarshalJSON` on the `Name` type doesn't work: https://play.golang.org/p/Fw7wBrwu9c

Comment: @hlin117 you misunderstood me, your last sentence wishes for UnmarshalJSON on Name which you very well can do, just put a * on it. https://play.golang.org/p/ejIfnfwO-R

Comment: @hlin117 also please [read this](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#pointers_vs_values).

Comment: Thanks @mkopriva. Your Golang example is what I'm looking for. Can you put it in the response to this question?

Comment: @hlin117 I think you can mark [maerics's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47339788/965900) since he updated it appropriately.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See the [`json.Marshaler`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshaler) and [`json.Unmarshaler`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshaler) types in the `encoding/json` package which allow you to define custom JSON en/decoding functions for arbitrary types.

```
package main

import (
  "encoding/json"
  "fmt"
)

type Name struct {
  CommonName     string
  ScientificName string
}

func (n *Name) UnmarshalJSON(bytes []byte) error {
  var name string
  err := json.Unmarshal(bytes, &name)
  if err != nil {
    return err
  }
  n.CommonName = name
  n.ScientificName = ""
  return nil
}

type Elephant struct {
  Name Name `json:"name"`
  Age  int  `json:"age"`
}

func main() {
  alice := Elephant{}
  aliceJson := `{"name":"Alice","age":2}`
  err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(aliceJson), &alice)
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
  fmt.Printf("%#v\n", alice)
}
// main.Elephant{Name:main.Name{CommonName:"Alice", ScientificName:""}, Age:2}
```

Comment: I tried that, it doesn't seem to work: https://play.golang.org/p/Fw7wBrwu9c.

And I don't want to define it on the `Elephant`, `Feline`, nor `Bear` structs. It's not a scalable solution.

Comment: @hlin117 see the code example, the trick is that the Marshaler must return a valid JSON value, e.g. a string in this case

Comment: The code example is for serializing (marshaling) an object. I need an example for unmarshaling.

Comment: @hlin117 the inverse of the example would be a receiver function with signature `MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error)`