# Unmarshalling json to use one of the object value as a key

Tags: go

Hello all,
I have a json that looks like something below ...

```
[
  {
    "Delay": 0.031247,
    "Index": {
      "Currency": "USD",
      "Valoren": "998434",
    },
    "IdentifierType": "Symbol",
    "Identifier": "SPX.INDCBSX",
  },
  {
    "Delay": 0,
    "Index": {
      "Currency": "USD",
      "Valoren": "13190963",
    },
    "IdentifierType": "Symbol",
    "Identifier": "SPDVXT.INDCBSX",
  }
]
```

I want to unmarshall it in such a way that I should be able to store it as `map[string]interface{}`, where key is value of "Identifier" value. For example if I write `data["SPX.INDCBSX"]` then I should get complete array element data. Of course I can unmarshall it by creating similar structure and iterating over it and creating map of this type but it is more time consuming operation.

Comment: Then write your own Unmarshaler. SO questions are full of it.

Comment: can you describe more about output you need from this implementation?

Answer (score 1):

There's no magic way to tell `encoding/json` to unmarshal this data for you while selecting a custom field as the key of the map. You have several options:

1. Implement the `json.Unmarshaler` interface; see the docs of `encoding/json` and for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47339542/defining-custom-unmarshalling-for-non-built-in-types).
2. Unmarshal the data into `[]map[string]interface{}` and then rejigger it into the format you want in a separate loop.
3. Use something like [JSON-to-Go](https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/) to create the structures representing your data and then doing (2) is much simpler, but this only works of the structure of your JSON data is rigid.

[This post](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2020/representing-json-structures-in-go/) can also be helful. [And this one](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2019/go-json-cookbook/).